# CKEditor 5 - Can I add Advanced Tab from CKEditor 4?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm upgrading from CKEditor 4 to 5, and some key functionality needs to be replaced.

In CKEditor 4, there is an optional 'Advanced' tab in Table Properties.

[CKEditor 4 Advanced Table Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KKOt.png)

In CKEditor 5, there is no other tab for this, despite adding every "table" plugin.

[CKEditor 5 Table Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZP6a.png)

I removed plugins until discovering this behavior comes from the "Advanced Tab for Dialog" plugin. I do not see this plugin in the CKEditor 5 builder, does this plugin still exist or is there a way to make this behavior with other plugins?